# Why does my code suddenly stop working when I add a "for loop" (Using VBA to retrieve XML)

Tags: xml, vba, loops, for-loop

**This code works:**

```
Dim node
Set node = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("root/options/option_element[0]/value/text()")
For j = 0 To node.Length - 1
    .Content.InsertAfter node(j).NodeValue
 Next j
.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
Set node = Nothing

Set node = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("root/options/option_element[1]/value/text()")
For j = 0 To node.Length - 1
    .Content.InsertAfter node(j).NodeValue
 Next j
.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
Set node = Nothing
```

**But this code doesn't work when I add a for loop - why?**
(There's no action performed. Nothing gets put onto the Word Document)

```
For i = 0 To 1
    Dim node As Object //declaring variable
    Set node = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("root/options/option_element[i]/value/text()") 
    For j = 0 To node.Length - 1
        .Content.InsertAfter node(j).NodeValue 
     Next j
    .Content.InsertParagraphAfter //this just adds a new line to the doc
    Set node = Nothing
Next i
```

**(Using Excel VBA Macro to retrieve XML)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set node = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("root/options/option_element[i]/value/text()")
```

should be

```
Set node = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("root/options/option_element[" & i & "]/value/text()")
```

In your first example you're using a literal "i" and not the *value* of `i`